# Complex numbers on the values of i

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to calculate:

1. $i^2 \div 3$
2. $i^i$
3. $(i+1)^{i-1}$.

For the first one, $i = \frac{1}{2}\cdot e^i\cdot\pi$.

So, $(\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^i\cdot\pi)^2 \div 3$, and I tried this trick for the other two but it is not getting me anywhere.

Comment: At least i^i was the subject of a recent question (which got the proper answer one can imagine) and maybe more of them.

Comment: I hope you mean $i = e^{i\pi/2}$.  And was (1) supposed to be $i^{2/3}$?

Comment: for (1) I wanted i^2/3 and can you do the explanation without using cis? Thanks

Comment: You really wanted $i^2/3$, that is, $(i^2)/3$?  Do you know what $i^2$ is?

Answer (score 1):

The general definition of $a^b$ (for $a \ne 0$) is $e^{b \log a}$.  But you have to be careful with this because it is a multivalued function if $b$ is not an integer: $\log a$ has infinitely many values.  So for example $\log(i) = i (\pi/2 + 2 n \pi)$ for arbitrary integers $n$.  Thus in (2),
$$ i^i = e^{i \log(i)} = e^{-(\pi/2 + 2 n \pi)}$$